# Setup for C# Winforms project that uses a database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, installation

I have a C# Winforms (.NET) project which is finished. For its database, I'm using SQL Server. I created a setup file using Visual Studio Installer extension.

The setup file is ok and the application is installed properly, but the application can't connect to a SQL Server database.

I'm really confused about how I should let my code connect to a SQL Server database on another PC which doesn't have SQL Server. And I don't want to install SQL Server on that PC.

Note: I'm using ADO.NET data model for communicating with the SQL Server database

Comment: Can you print on the printer in your friends house? Pretty much the same goes for your database. Your friend can not connect to a database hosted on your pc. Unless you recieve a static IP from your internet provider I'd suggest to host your database in the cloud somewhere

Comment: This does not make sense to me _at all_. If your Application uses SQL Server, it needs to be installed _somewhere_. So either you provide an option to install it or a configuration to obtain the connection string. Why didn't you consider this _at the beginning_? If several of your clients need to access it, it must be network reachable, of course.

Comment: localhost is always the computer on which the application runs. If you run SQL server on a specific PC, then use the name of that PC for the connection, not localhost. Ideally you make the name of that PC configurable, just in case something goes wrong with that SQL server instance

Comment: If the database is intended a local data store, where each PC install has it's own DB, then SQL Server was a **very poor choice**. As the name implies, it's a **server** database... it expects to be installed to run as server and use resources _all the time_, even when the application is closed, and it expects dedicated hardware where it can do things like use as much RAM as possible for caching data. And I say this as someone who makes a significant part of my living working specifically with SQL Server. Instead, you should think about an **in-process** engine like SQLite or even Access.

Comment: [continued] On the other hand, if this is to be a shared database, where several Users/PCs need to interact with the same data, then SQL Server is a great option... but you need to suck it up and go through the installation process on a _dedicated_  PC to host the server for this shared data.

Comment: Don't waste time configuring remote access to a SQL database installed on a local network with a static external IP. With little money, you can buy a domain and hosting space on which to put your SQL database, and it will be effortlessly accessible from anywhere in the world.

Comment: @FabioCaruso It's not recommended to expose SQL Server directly to the public internet.

Comment: It's obvious that the best solution could be a ASP.NET Core MVC application on cloud. But, in this case, it's better to have a database on protected cloud than having it on protected (?) PC with SQL ports open to the Network.